# HackReactor, coding window now has access to an object called "Admissions" with a method named "showApp". Call this method without any arguments?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, arguments

the question is..   Your coding window now has access to an object called "Admissions" with a method named "showApp". Call this method without any arguments?

I am processing to apply for Hack Reactor Admissions Challenge. I will need help with those question please...

I was thought answer is

```
 function Admissions()
 {
  alert("showApp");
 }

 Admissions();
```

Answer (score 1):

as the instructions say showApp() is a method of the Admissions object, so you must call it through Admissions in the following way:

```
Admissions.showApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that.... you're seriously not ready and I doubt you'll pass the technical interview if you couldn't figure that out yourself.

Also, what the code does is define a variable Admissions that is bound to an anonymous function. That function returns showApp (Assumed probably undefined). You then use the Admission handle to call the anonymous function.
If you have a pre-existing object Admissions with a showApp method, all you need is:

Admissions.showApp();

Answer (score 0):

showApp is a method. Since you're asked to access "Admissions" (Object), you access it by using the object followed by a period and then the method name. Since you're passing the method with no arguments the insides of the parentheses are empty.

```
Admissions.showApp()
```

Answer (score 0):

In javaScript method of an object accessed by a dot(.) sign.

```html
Applications.showApp();
```